# ModuleNotFoundError after successful pip install in Google Colaboratory

Tags: python, pip, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to import a package I wrote into a Google Colaboratory notebook. I uploaded the package contents to my Drive, then ran:

```
[ ] from google.colab import drive
[ ] drive.mount('content/gdrive/')
[ ] ! pip install --user /content/gdrive/My\ Drive/my-package
Processing ./gdrive/My Drive/my-package
Building wheels for collected packages: my-package
  Building wheel for my-package (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for my-package: 
  Stored in directory: 
Successfully built my-package
Installing collected packages: my-package
Successfully installed my-package-1.0.0.dev1
```

`pip list` shows the package has been successfully installed. However, imports of the package fail with a `ModuleNotFoundError`.

I've successfully pip installed and imported my-package on my local machine. I've also successfully installed and imported another Python package through the same Colab notebook using `pip install --user`. As mentioned [here](https://github.com/google/unrestricted-adversarial-examples/issues/42), I've also tried restarting the kernel.

This may be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56939487/google-colaboratory-local-module-modulenotfounderror) related but unanswered question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @jojo's suggestion, I uninstalled and reinstalled the package on my local machine and was able to diagnose the problem. On both my local machine and in Colab I was able to successfully install and import the package only when including the `-e` (editable) flag in the `pip` command (`pip install --user -e /content/gdrive/My\ Drive/my-package`), and restarting the runtime after installation). I have no idea why including the `-e` flag would make a difference; please comment if you have any insight!

Comment: Restarting the runtime (Jupyter notebook kernel in my case) helped

Answer (score 7):

The github page you linked to about restarting the runtime was a little ambiguous IMO, so I just wanted to clarify:

You need to run the `!pip install` cell. *Then* "Restart Runtime." *Then* run your `import` statement cell.

I might suggest you "Reset all Runtimes" before performing these steps, just to make sure you have a clean slate.

-- If the above steps *are* what you already did:
Are you using a Python 2 or 3 notebook? (not 100% sure why that would matter, but more info would be good)

Did you `pip install` to your local machine from the google drive link? (If not, try to see if that works and report back)

Comment: I'm using a Python 3 notebook.

Answer (score 6):

The editable install (or [setuptools development-mode](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#development-mode)) appends the module path to an `easy-install.pth` file. The `site` module processes these files when python is started and appends the paths to `sys.path`. That's why it works only after restarting the runtime.

One can avoid restarting the colab notebook by importing the `site` module and (re)running `site.main()`.

```
%pip install -e pkg
import site
site.main()
import pkg
```

However in the example below this has the effect of removing the current directory from `sys.path` and replacing it with its absolute path.

```
%pip install -e "git+https://github.com/jd/tenacity#egg=tenacity"

print("\nTrying to import tenacity")
try:
    import tenacity
except ImportError as exc:
    print("ImportError")
    print(exc)
    print()

import sys, site

print("\n##### sys.path original #####")
for p in sys.path:
    print(f"'{p}'")
print()

site.main()

print("\n##### sys.path after site.main() #####")
for p in sys.path:
    print(f"'{p}'")
print()

import tenacity
print(f"\nImported tenacity from {tenacity.__file__}")
```

Prints

```
Obtaining tenacity from git+https://github.com/jd/tenacity#egg=tenacity
  Cloning https://github.com/jd/tenacity to ./src/tenacity
  Running command git clone -q https://github.com/jd/tenacity /content/src/tenacity
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from tenacity) (1.15.0)
Installing collected packages: tenacity
  Running setup.py develop for tenacity
Successfully installed tenacity

Trying to import tenacity
ImportError
No module named 'tenacity'


##### sys.path original #####
''
'/env/python'
'/usr/lib/python36.zip'
'/usr/lib/python3.6'
'/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload'
'/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages'
'/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages'
'/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/extensions'
'/root/.ipython'


##### sys.path after site.main() #####
'/content'
'/env/python'
'/usr/lib/python36.zip'
'/usr/lib/python3.6'
'/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload'
'/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages'
'/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages'
'/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/extensions'
'/root/.ipython'
'/content/src/tenacity'


Imported tenacity from /content/src/tenacity/tenacity/__init__.py
```

Example colab notebook: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1S5EU-MirhaTWz1JJVdos3GcojmOSLC1C?usp=sharing

Stumbled onto this via the blog post: https://yidatao.github.io/2016-05-10/Python-easyinstall-generates-pth-file/